# Modify Hibernate entity onSave

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

Signed in user creates a project. I would like to update createdBy field of ProjectModel before persist to DB.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECTS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public @Data class ProjectModel extends BaseModel {

    @Length(min = 4, max = 30)
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User createdBy;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID")
    private List<RinexFileModel> rinexFileModels;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status = Status.NEW;

    public void addRinexFiles(List<RinexFileModel> rinexFiles) {
        this.rinexFileModels.addAll(rinexFiles);
    }

    public void addRinexFile(RinexFileModel rinexFile) {
        this.rinexFileModels.add(rinexFile);
    }

    public enum Status {
        NEW, READY, PROCESSING, PROCESSED
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }
}
```

There are at least two options to do it.

- By callback methods (**@PrePersist**, etc.) Similar to code below but I need UserModel and access to spring bean

  similar to this SpringContext [example](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Super+simple+approach+to+accessing+Spring+beans+from+non-Spring+managed+classes+and+POJOs)

[image]
This approach I don't like because of the single responsibility principle has been broken I think so.

- Interceptor (EmptyInterceptor)

  [image: enter code here]

**HibernateInterceptorImpl Interceptor**

```
public class HibernateInterceptorImpl extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Resource
    private HibernateInterceptorStrategy hibernateInterceptorStrategy;

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {
        boolean entityChanged = false;

        final EmptyInterceptor interceptor = hibernateInterceptorStrategy.getStrategy(entity);

        if (nonNull(interceptor)) {
            entityChanged = interceptor.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
        }

        return entityChanged;
    }
}

@Component("hibernateInterceptorStrategy")
public class HibernateInterceptorStrategy {

    @Resource
    private Map<Class, EmptyInterceptor> hibernateInterceptorStrategies;

    public EmptyInterceptor getStrategy(Object object) {
        for (Class clazz : hibernateInterceptorStrategies.keySet()) {
            if (object.getClass() == clazz) {
                return hibernateInterceptorStrategies.get(clazz);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The ProjectInterceptor implemenation

```
public class ProjectInterceptorImpl extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Resource
    private SessionService sessionService;

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {
        final ProjectModel project = (ProjectModel) entity;

        if (isNull(project.getCreatedBy())) {
            project.setCreatedBy(sessionService.getCurrentUser());
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Debug results (User successfully added, but nevertheless exception on @NotNull validation for createdBy)

[image]

[image]

FIX IS: modify state array as well. But don't have a good solution for this.

[image]

Comment: Do you check @CreatedBy annotations from jpa audit?

Comment: Yes it works now

Answer (score 1):

To populate user data before model saves could be used *Spring Data* **@CreateBy** annotation.
Check this [article](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/created-by-and-last-modified-by.html) first

**User + embedded class UserPrincipal was changed to UserPrincipal only** due to spring security based on User Service returns UserPrincipal. So, not a big deal for my project to change it into one user model

[image]

**Enable JPA Audit**
[image]

**Result**
[image]